# How to change the datepicker calendra view in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

In angular material datepicker when click on calendar button it open date and than on clicking in month it show year. I want to select the year first than  month and don't want to show date on calendar, it also show on same format once the year and month selected form the calendar in MM/YYYY format only.

[image]